# Can I make tubular hole at the edge of the face without bool operations?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I wonder if this process could be done some other way.

Lets say I want to get this result, but without boolean.
[image: Made with bool-difference]

I could think of only one way and it is beveling. I make loopcut, then push one edge inside the cube and bevel it, also I used 2 more loopcuts to  limit the beveling, but it does not look circular. Do you have any trick for that?
[image]

Comment: I don't fully understand why you would not want to use the Boolean modifier, when it gives you the desired result. If you need to have the geometry editable, then just apply the modifier and delete the subtracting object.

Comment: From scratch. eg make ngon from  square and circle and extrude?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Front row:

- Subdivided Plane
- Central faces selected: Loop Tools > Circle ( or Space Bar > Circle )
- Delete appropriate faces

Back row:

- Extrude
- Bevel Modifier,  angle-based, (not catching curve), Segments:2 Profile:1
- Subdivision Modifier

[image]

(Close-up of bevel result)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it in quads you could do something like this.

You need to activate the loop tools add-on and use the circle function.
Sorry for the poor quality gif. I hope it is clear what I did there.

Here is a brief summary.

I made a plane and scaled it x 2 so I can cut it in half later.

Added some edge loops in both directions and scaled them down in X or Y direction.

Selected a square of vertices and clicked the circle button in loop tools.

Cut out the circle, cut off half of the plane and then extruded it up.

[image]

Comment: Could you please write down most important steps to not to relay only on overly long gif?

Comment: @cgslav yes, you are right. I edited my post.